# Rspec: nil.should_not be_nil passes when I expect failure. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Doing some rspec work in a Rails project. Kind curious why these should_not be_nil expectations pass. Any thoughts?

```
it "nils should be nil" do
  @io = nil
  @io.should_not be_nil #passes (shouldn't!!)
  nil.should_not be_nil #passes (shouldn't!!)
  @io.should == nil # passes
  @io.should be_nil # passes
  @io.nil?.should be_true # passes
  #@io.nil?.should be_false # fails as expected
end
```

**UPDATE:** Based on feedback here I've been able isolate the cause of this (which is from things loaded in the `spec_helper`). I believe it's due to a poor swizzling of `.nil?`  or `.blank?` which I'm going to have a talk to the dev to see if these overrides are really necessary at all.

Thanks to those who helped verify my stuff.

Comment: Well that's not what https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-10/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers says should happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can not reproduce your statements. I wrote them in a fake spec in an existing project like this.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Pepper" do
  describe "simplicity" do
  before(:each) { @io = nil }
  # should fail
  it 'should be nil 1' do
    @io.should_not be_nil 
  end
  # should fail
  it 'should be nil 2' do
    nil.should_not be_nil 
  end
  # should NOT fail
  it 'should be nil 3' do
    @io.should == nil
  end
  # should NOT fail
  it 'should be nil 4' do   
    @io.should be_nil
  end
  # should NOT fail
  it 'should be nil 5' do
    @io.nil?.should be_true # passes
  end
  # should fail
  it 'should be nil 6' do
    @io.nil?.should be_false 
  end
  end
end
```

which returns - as expected - the following output:

```
simplicity
should be nil 1 (FAILED - 1)
should be nil 2 (FAILED - 2)
should be nil 3
should be nil 4
should be nil 5
should be nil 6 (FAILED - 3)
```

So maybe your spec_helper is implying something, that is irritating your specs.

Comment: Yep. I tried the same and can verify the results. Even more it is impossible that `should_not be_nil` and `should be_nil` give the same result, unless you have defined your own function `be_nil` whose results are less predictable. `be_nil` just calls `nil?` in rspec.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah I'll look into it some more to see what's up. I don't think we overrid anything but maybe some of the third party code we use did.